# Im not sure how to take filename out of sha256 checksum in Python 3

Tags: python, checksum

I'm still a Python noob but figured that instead of checking a checksum manually, I would make a quick program so it would take less time whenever I had to do it(also as practice) so I wrote this(excuse the extra useless lines and bad naming in my code, I was trying to pinpoint what I was doing wrong.)

```
import subprocess

FileLocation = input("Enter File Location: ")

Garbage1 = str(input("Enter First Checksum: "))

Garbage2 = str(subprocess.call(['sha256sum', FileLocation]))

Garbage3 = Garbage2.split(None, 1)

if Garbage1 == Garbage3[0]:
    print("all good")
else:
    print("Still Not Working!!!")
```

When I run this code it keeps on leaving the filepath at the end of the second checksum because of the Linux command, but I tried getting rid of it various ways with .split() but when I ran the code, it was still there, I also tried to add the file path to the end of the first checksum as a test, but that also won't add the filepath to the end of it.
I do know for a fact that the checksums match

Any idea whats wrong any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when printing Garbage2  ? Also name your variable in in lowercase

Comment: Have you tried `Garbage2.split(" ")` ?

Comment: `subprocess.call` returns an integer process exit code.

Comment: Try with https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: fwiw, there's a `hashlib` module with a [`sha256`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms) function built in to python!

Comment: Sorry about the capitalized variables I don't usually do that I was just in a hurry.

Comment: thx for the info anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, `subprocess.call` does: *Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete or timeout, then return the returncode attribute.* You can verify this in the python shell by entering `help(subprocess.call)` or looking at https://docs.python.org and searching for the `subprocess` module.

Your code converts the integer return code to a string, not the checksum. There are other calls in subprocess that capture the process stdout, which is where `sha256sum` sends its checksum. Stdout is a `bytes` object that needs to be decoded to a string.

```
import subprocess

FileLocation = input("Enter File Location: ")

Garbage1 = str(input("Enter First Checksum: "))

Garbage2 = subprocess.check_output(['sha256sum', FileLocation]).decode()

Garbage3 = Garbage2.split(None, 1)

if Garbage1 == Garbage3[0]:
    print("all good")
else:
    print("Still Not Working!!!")
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, I am still not very good and was trying to figure out why it was throwing intType errors, which was why i tried converting it to a string like an idiot.